# How do I make something visible only when I'm looking at it?

Tags: xna, c#

So I'm making a basic 2D game in C# XNA. I want it so wherever my character is facing there is a cone of light and only that part of the level is visible while the right of the screen is dark. Please excuse my ignorance, I haven't been working with C# too long.

Comment: Have you done any reading on 2D lighting in general? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Take a look at Catalin's Game Development Blog
 http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/dynamic-2d-shadows/

Answer (score 8):

Well the simplest approach to this would be to simply overlay a dark mask over the right side of the screen. You could do this with a completely opaque black image that covers stuff from view, but I think what would look better is a semi-transparent black image so that you can still see the background and then hide the enemy graphics on that side of the screen.

Comment: With the modification of rotating the cone to follow the view of the character, this is going to be the best solution.

Comment: I imagined a solution with multiplication against a lighting map, but this is actually simple and very effective. +1

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you mean. Are you saying that I should lay a semi transparent black image for the entire screen? How would the cone vision with this method?

Comment: @Ady yes, that's what he's saying. The cone would be a transparent area in the black image; rotate and position it to always point from the player to wherever he's looking.